# Return matching nodes in a nested tree: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that is implemented as a tree with the follwing structure. I am trying to implement a  search functionality that basically searches the key inside these objects and return them by maintaining the relationship.

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com",
    config: {
      val1: false,
      val2: false
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
        config: {
          val1: true,
          val2: true
        },
        children: [
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1",
            config: {
              val1: true,
              val2: true
            },
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild2",
            config: {
              val1: false,
              val2: true
            },
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
        config: {
          val1: true,
          val2: false
        },
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorpwebsite.com.child1",
        className: "level-1 leaf",
        children: [],
        val1: false,
        val2: false
      }
    ],
    config: {
      val1: false,
      val2: false
    }
  }
];
```

Here I need to search the array based on key "name" recursively , and return that object maintaining the parent-child relationship. THe search should be a `contains` search

Code that  I tried:

```
function result(input) {
  let res = arr.map((item) => {
    if (item.name === input) return item;
  });
  return res;
}
console.log(result("website"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...and return them by maintaining the relationship..."*?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ideally the hierarchy of parent-child should be intact.

Comment: Some notes on the bit of code you've posted: `map` isn't a filtering operation, there's no attempt at handling nesting shown, and you've said the search should be a "contains" search, but you've used equality  (`===`) in your code.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by that. The child elements don't point back to their parents, so if you isolate them from their parents, by nature you're going to lose that relationship. Could you show us the resulting structure you expect when you search for (say) `"internalcorp.com.grand"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, you can play with it here: [Codepen Playground](https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/gOxOPZZ?editors=0011)
I've made the search to case insensitive and you can also search for multiple words, it should give you full tree and maintain parent-child relationship, try it out

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com",
    config: { val1: false, val2: false },
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
        config: { val1: true, val2: true },
        children: [
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1",
            config: { val1: true, val2: true },
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild2",
            config: { val1: false, val2: true },
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
        config: { val1: true, val2: false },
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorpwebsite.com.child1",
        className: "level-1 leaf",
        children: [],
        val1: false,
        val2: false
      }
    ],
    config: {
      val1: false,
      val2: false
    }
  }
];
function result(input) {
  const v = input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
  const regex = new RegExp(v.trim().replace(" ", "|"), "i");
  return arr.filter(function f(o) {
    let found = false;
    if (regex.test(o.name)) found = true;
    if (o.children) {
      const x = o.children.filter(f);
      if (x.length) {
        o.children = x;
        return true;
      }
      return found;
    }
  });
}
console.log(result("website.com"));
```